# Laravel "function name must be a string" error on saving a model when code is executing second pass in a scheduled loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am running a daily schedule in Laravel 5.5 which selects matching Posts and runs a foreach loop that calls a static function in PostController, editing the Post model and saving it afterwards.

When the code is executed, everything works fine on the first loop with the first post, but on the second pass, I get the `function name must be a string` error on when the function attempts saving the model.

Here is the schedule in `kernel.php`

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    $posts = DB::table('post')
        ->where('finish_time', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->where('expiry_processed_at', '=', null)
        ->get()->all();

    if(count($posts) > 0){
        foreach ($posts as $post){
            PostController::processExpiry($post->post_id);
        }
    }
})->everyMinute();
```

And here is the function it calls in PostController:

```
public static function processExpiry($post_id){
    $post = Study::find($post_id);
    $latestLicense = $post->licenses->last();

    $email = $post->user->email;
    $param = ['post' => $post];

    \Mail::send(['html' => 'emails.post_expiry', 'text' => 'emails.txt.post_expiry'], $param, function ($message) use ($email) {
        $message->to($email)
            ->subject(trans('email_subject.post_expiry'));
    });

    // Identify post as processed
    $post->expiry_processed_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

    $validator = \Validator::make(
        $post->toArray(),
        $post->rules
    );
    Log::info(print_r($post,true));
    try {
        $post->saveOrFail(); // This is the line where error occurs on second pass
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // catch is never triggered
        $messages = $e->getMessage();
        return (Object) array('status' => false, 'error_message' => 'Error saving post to database');
    }
    // return because same function can be called manually by user
    return (Object) array('status' => true);
}
```

`Log::info()` of `$post` before `$post->saveOrFail();` outputs:

```
[2018-02-01 10:25:00] local.INFO: App\Models\Post Object
(
    [table:protected] => post
    [timestamps] => 
    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => edit_time
        )

    [incrementing] => 1
    [primaryKey] => post_id
    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => deleted_at
        )

    [refundThreshold] => 10
    [rules] => Array
        (

            [user_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => required
                    [1] => integer
                )

            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => required
                    [1] => max:255
                    [2] => App\Rules\NotUrl Object
                        (
                        )
                )
            [description] => Array
                (
                    [0] => required
                )

            [finish_time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => sometimes
                    [1] => max:32
                    [2] => min:10
                )

            [status] => Array
                (
                    [0] => integer
                )

            [create_time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => max:32
                )

            [create_ip] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ip
                )

            [edit_time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => max:32
                )

            [edit_ip] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ip
                )

        )

    [connection:protected] => mysql
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 7
            [user_id] => 167
            [description] => Lorem ipsum
            [finish_time] => 2016-07-01 00:00:00
            [expiry_processed_at] => 2018-02-01 10:25:00
            [status] => 1
            [create_time] => 2018-01-30 21:27:11
            [create_ip] => 
            [edit_time] => 2014-01-31 21:28:27
            [edit_ip] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 7
            [user_id] => 167
            [description] => Lorem ipsum
            [finish_time] => 2016-07-01 00:00:00
            [expiry_processed_at] => 
            [status] => 1
            [create_time] => 2014-02-05 21:27:11
            [create_ip] => 
            [edit_time] => 2014-08-11 15:54:22
            [edit_ip] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [licenses] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [forceDeleting:protected] => 
)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you before 
$post->saveOrFail();

debug $post variable using var_dump($post) or simple dd($post);

Comment: Good point, I've added the log of the variable in question, but it's no different than the one before (other than being the object for a different  post)

Comment: still not understandable. Is our log exact post before that error?

One more thing. Why don't you put the whole post to the controller's method instead of $post-> post_id ?

if(count($posts) > 0){
        foreach ($posts as $post){
            PostController::processExpiry($post);
        }
    }


In this case you will not have to do Study::find($post_id);. You will have already $post.

And pay attention. By default laravel expects primary key = 'id'. So when u do ::find  - laravel searches by field 'id'. If you didn't set primary_key in your model - it might cause an error.

Comment: The function is called from two different places and it makes sense to pass in the id in the other location. Yes, primary keys have been set in the model. The code works fine - the first time the loop runs, its the second iteration that is the issue. And I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

so your code would be like this

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    $posts = DB::table('post')
        ->where('finish_time', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->where('expiry_processed_at', '=', null)
        ->get()->all();

    if(count($posts) > 0){
        foreach ($posts as $post){
            PostController::processExpiry($post);
        }
    }
})->everyMinute();
```

Controller:

```
public static function processExpiry($post){
    $latestLicense = $post->licenses->last();

    $email = $post->user->email;
    $param = ['post' => $post];

    \Mail::send(['html' => 'emails.post_expiry', 'text' => 'emails.txt.post_expiry'], $param, function ($message) use ($email) {
        $message->to($email)
            ->subject(trans('email_subject.post_expiry'));
    });

    // Identify post as processed
    $post->expiry_processed_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

    $validator = \Validator::make(
        $post->toArray(),
        $post->rules
    );
    Log::info(print_r($post,true));
    try {
        $post->saveOrFail(); // This is the line where error occurs on second pass
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // catch is never triggered
        $messages = $e->getMessage();
        return (Object) array('status' => false, 'error_message' => 'Error saving post to database');
    }
    // return because same function can be called manually by user
    return (Object) array('status' => true);
}
```